# Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A0401) when calling WCF created as COM

Tags: vbscript, wcf-client

I am calling a wcf service created as a COM. I can call the service and service is inserting data correctly. But when i am trying to get a string value returned from wcf method i am getting this error. Not sure what iam doing wrong.

Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A0401)
Expected end of statement
Value = Obj.GetString "TEST","123.*"

```
enter code here

<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<%
        Dim Obj
        Dim Value      


    Set Obj = Server.CreateObject("WCFCom.IClass")
    Value = Obj.GetString "TEST","123.*"    

 %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling a function or method with arguments uses parens;

```
Value = Obj.GetString("TEST","123.*")
```